# Monero GUI Changing from host node to local node

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, full-node, synchronization, remote-access

I have deposited coins into my Monero GUI wallet prior to the completion of full node synchronization. My coins are not visible and synchronization is very slow for me, currently 5 days with still around 91000 blocks remaining.

If I change to a remote node, will this change my wallet address or will I lose my coins?

Answer (score 3):

With Monero, the daemon takes care of syncing the blockchain, while the wallet handles private keys. The daemon never has access to private keys [1], only the wallet does. Therefore, if you switch daemons, your wallet address does not change, as long as you continue loading the same wallet. The wallet software will just scan for blocks from a different source of blocks.

[1] this will soon change a little, as the daemon will gain the ability to scan the chain using a wallet's private view key, but this isn't relevant here.

Answer (score 1):

> If i change to a remote node, will this change my wallet address or will I lose my coins?

no and no